# jQuery-1.9.0.js Line 2184 "Invalid procedure call or argument" using jQuery.inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Using jQuery 1.9.0 and [jQuery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) and trying to submit a form using $.ajax() while removing the inputmask throws an error. The unmasked value is need to be submitted in a `$.ajax` call. After removing the inputmask with `.inputmask("remove")` yields the error "Invalid procedure call or argument" when calling the `.val()` function but only in Internet Explorer. Calling `.val()` on the input before removing the inputmask works. How can the unmasked value be gotten out of the input element without throwing an error in IE?

```
$("input[name=Percent]").inputmask("remove");
var percent $('input[name=Percent]').val();
$("input[name=Percent]").inputmask("999%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `$("#Percent").inputmask("remove");` before and after there is a a way to get the value [unmasked](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#unmaskedvalue) built into jQuery.inputmask.

```
var percent = $('input[name=Percent]').inputmask('unmaskedvalue');
```

Using the built in functionality keeps Internet Explorer happy. This took me quite some time to find so I thought I would share it here in case someone else has this problem.

Comment: ... That code couldn't possibly be working. You're missing the `=` between `percent` and `$`...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out I made a mistake in copying the code from more complex solution. I will edit it and fix that line. It should `var percent = $('input[name=Percent]').inputmask('unmaskedvalue');`